# Creating a report showing record details with VS2010

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

Is there a way I can design a report (using VS2010, ASP.Net), which will list customers in the following format:

Id:     1
Name:   Joe Bloggs
Address:Address 1
        City
        ZIP
        State1

Id:     2
Name:   Steve Brown
Address:Address 2
        City2
        ZIP2
        State2
...

Can I have such a format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `List` to iterate through each record and add the item template for each employee.
In your case you should group your list by the EmplyeeID field, that will make each `ListItem` show a single record of an Employee.

Inside the List place: 5 labels for each field, e.g. ID, Name etc..
Next to each label place a text box and attach it to the DataSet fields provided by the list element.

here is an example for you: [Using Lists - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee224216%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)